# counting answers from only male users

Tags: mysql, database

I have database like this:

```
+-----+---------+--------------+
| id  | user_id | form_answers |
+-----+---------+--------------+
|  1  |    1    | yes          |
|  2  |    1    | M            |
|  3  |    2    | yes          |
|  4  |    2    | M            |
|  5  |    3    | no           |
|  6  |    3    | F            |
|  7  |    4    | no           |
|  8  |    4    | M            |
+-----+---------+--------------+
```

There was a form that inserted to this database . It had one question and dropdown list (male of female). Is it possible to count how many "yes" answers the male (M) users gave? It doesn't have to be counted...it can just select of all rows with answer "yes" from male users.

Comment: Why do you have such a schema? Cant you have something like [`id`, `user_id`, `gender`, `answer`]?

Comment: I'm afraid it's someone elses really really old form that never had to be analyzed this way. It has more than 22k of inserts right now so manual counting is out of the question. I did coust answers by using MYSQL inside php loop so i know right number but it takes forever to do that operation as it makes alot of queries as you can imagine so i'm trying to speed it up. Last resort will be redesigning database and switching data around

Comment: what will be your desired result based on the sample records above?

Comment: @JW. result would be: 2 (as in 2 males gave answer "yes")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join answers tabe with itself. This will return the list of "yes" answers male users gave:

```
SELECT a1.*
FROM answers a1 inner join answers a2
     on a1.user_id=a2.user_id
        and a1.form_answers='yes'
        and a2.form_answers='M'
```

to count the rows, just substitute the select line with this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
```

see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36550/5).

Comment: This did the trick. I cant believe how fast you guys and gals are in giving answers. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) totalUsers
FROM
    (
        SELECT  user_id
        FROM    tableName
        WHERE   form_answers IN ('YES','M')
        GROUP   BY user_ID
        HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
    ) s
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c742d/4)